# Implement a slideshow-like frontpage with text overlays

Tags: frontpage, text, slideshow

I am looking for a WordPress solution - may be the appropriate theme or a combination of theme/plugin/widgets... - for the following:

- the front page of the site should present a series of fullscreen "slides"
  through which the visitor can scroll, either horizontally or
  vertically

  - each slide has a separate background image
  - overlayed over the background image is content with custom layout, e.g. multi-column text and icons

Here is an example for the desired look of one of these slides:

[image]

Slides of this type can be stacked vertically on the page, or there could be left-right buttons to flip through them horizontally.

Comment: The question is too broad for code samples, hope my answer  helps you getting on the right track though.

Comment: Try using [revolution slider](https://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380)

Comment: There are a ton of jQuery sliders out there...just create a child theme from the theme you are using -- and override home.php with your slider embedded there.

Comment: @CC care to recommend some of those sliders?

Comment: I've personally used Nivo, SlitSlider, bxslider, Flexslider (1 and 2) and lately "basic-slider".  I probably use Flexslider the most.  They all have their strengths and weaknesses, you just have to look at them and try them out.  If you know CSS it's a huge help as you can make them look like whatever you want.  I would not use a plugin for this, just do the simple child theme like I said; this is a very simple/easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

- You could look into a **plugin** that let's you add slides from backend (eg. *Slider Revolution*) and then you simply add the slider shortcode in a "Home" page, that you set as the front page through *Settings > Reading*, or run the slideshow from your `index.php` or `header.php`, depending how/where you want it.
- Or you could use a **Javascript** slider library (eg. *Swiper*), enqueue the necessary files from your `functions.php`, then create a custom post type "Slides" (eg. with a plugin like *Types*) where each "slide" post is a slide. Then you would build a query in `index.php` or `header.php`, that pulls each slides, like posts, and displays them with the structure needed for the library to work.